# Excel randomly select name from list with multiple entries and fill in a column not repeating the name more than once per group of lines

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula

I need your help guiding me to createa function in Excel that will help me fill in some records.

i have a list of names that i want to use to fill in a specific column

List of names:  TRANQUILIDADE, EDP, NOS and CARMIN

[image: example if list of names]

Then i will have columns that will  have lines already filled in with names (some are the same from my list others are not.) and blank line that need to be filled in with the list above mentioned. the names can not be repeated (so if within a group of line we already has "TRANQUILIDADE" this name can not be repeated within these group of lines)

[image: example of the column to fill in]

you will be able to see from the example that i have the first column that the code is unique for each group of 4 line and for each group of 4 line i might have one or more empty design name (lines in red)

I need a solution to fill in the red blanks.

can someone hit me to the right direction?

best regards,
victor

Comment: with a formula you will need to select each cell and paste the formula.  It would not be fillable through dragging.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will need to be pasted into each cell where the desired output is needed:

```
=INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($F$1:$F$4)/(COUNTIFS($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1),INDEX(A:A,ROW()),$C$1:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1),$F$1:$F$4)=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,4-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1),INDEX(A:A,ROW()),$C$1:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1),$F$1:$F$4)))))
```

This also assumes the the `Funiture Secondary Code` is unique per grouping.  That other grouping will not have the same code.

[image]